# Balls-into-bins problem: Lower bound for the bins which exactly have one ball

Tags: probability, algorithms, computer-science, balls-in-bins

Here is my problem:

If $n$ balls are thrown into $m$ bins (uniformly at random and independently) and $n < m$, can we prove:

With high probability (w.h.p) there are $\Theta(n)$ bins which exactly have one ball in them.

If we can, how to prove it?

I tried to calculate the expectation of one-ball-bins and then use Chernoff bound to solve it. But it was wrong because the random variables are not independent.

Sorry for my bad expression because I'm not very good at English. :-)

Comment: What is $\Theta(n)$? Is it the number which maximizes the probability?

Comment: It's the Big-Theta notation which describes the algorithm complexity. In this problem it means $kn$ ($k$ can be any constant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $m$ and $n$ are large, and let $\lambda = n/m$, where $n$ is the number of balls and $m$ is the number of bins.  Then according to Example III.10, page 177, in *Analytic Combinatorics* by Flajolet and Sedgewick (available online: [Analytic Combinatorics pdf](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)), in the limit as $n \to \infty$ with $n/m$ fixed, the average proportion of bins containing $s$ balls is
$$e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^s}{s!}$$
so the occupancy of a random bin in a random allocation satisfies a Poisson law in the limit.  In the case $s=1$, the average proportion containing one ball reduces to $e^{-\lambda} \lambda$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I believe your answer is what I need because using Poisson approximation is my teacher's hint. But I'm still confused: Why $e^{-\lambda} \lambda$ is $\Theta(n)$? By the way, If $m$ is large but $n$ is not, does your conclusion still hold? Because it seems that your conclusion holds when $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I don't know how the result in Analytic Combinatorics relates to $\Theta(n)$, and it may be that the result does not answer your question completely, since it only applies in the limit for large $n$.  However, if $n/m$ is fixed and $m \to \infty$, then it must be that $n \to \infty$ also.